# prev(); and next(); usage clarification Jquery

Tags: jquery, addclass, siblings

we have a series of divs, and we would like to assign different classes to the next and previous siblings of the currently selected DIV.

This is our code:

```
<div class="panel">DIV content 1</div>
<div class="panel current">DIV content 2</div> //THIS IS THE CURRENTLY SELECTED PANEL
<div class="panel">DIV content 3</div>
<div class="panel">DIV content 4</div>
<div class="panel">DIV content 5</div>
```

As I understood, the following JQuery code would look for siblings of .current and add the classes next and previous. But since it's looking for .current elements, it'll not find em.
How can I refer to the .current panel and addClass to the next and previous .panel elements?

Thank you.

```
$('.current').prev().addClass('previous');
$('.current').next().addClass('next');
```

Answer (score 4):

As per your needs, you may use [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/), [`prevUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/), [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/), [`prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) functions. The `next()` and `prev()` will get you to just one previous or next element respectively.

```
//To select all previous elements of `.current` element:
$('.current').prevAll('.panel').addClass('previous');
//To select all next elements of `.current` element:
$('.current').nextAll('.panel').addClass('next');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsdo.it/sarfraznawaz/rrmE)

Comment: No. I need JUST the directly next and previous siblings… 
The fact is that I don't know how to select the next and previous .panel elements starting from .current (which has .panel class in common with others)

Answer (score 1):

`$('.current').prev()` gives you one element before .current:

```
<div class="panel">DIV content 1</div>
```

`$('.current').next()` gives you one element after .current:

```
<div class="panel">DIV content 3</div>
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ssNUN/

If you want to get all prev or next elements use [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)() and [prevUntil](http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/)().

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YfV5x/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('.current').prevUntil('.panel:first').addClass('previous');
$('.current').nextUntil('.panel:last').addClass('next');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yxq39/

or:

```
$('.current').prevAll().addClass('previous');
$('.current').nextAll().addClass('next');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right
just add the following

```
$('.current').prev(".panel").addClass('previous');
$('.current').next(".panel").addClass('next');
```